# How to build a custom opencv.js with opencv_contrib

Tags: javascript, opencv, feature-detection, emscripten

I would like to include xfeatures2D from opencv_contrib into opencv.js.

I follow this documentation [Build OpenCV.js](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da1/tutorial_js_setup.html). Everything is ok. I got a brand new opencv.js that I'm able to use in my html page, but it doesn't include the xfeatures2D module.

I change this file opencv/platforms/js/build_js.py to add :

```
def get_cmake_cmd(self):
  cmd = ["cmake",
     "-DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/Users/me/git/opencv_contrib/modules",
     ...
```

Now cmake include opencv_contrib module. I can see extra modules compiled, but still not included by emscripten. It looks like JavaScript compilation hardcoded into opencv/modules/js.

Is a way to produce his own opencv.js and choose to remove or add opencv and/or contribution modules ?

Comment: could this be helpful https://html.developreference.com/article/11401179/sift+%3D+cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()+not+working+even+though+have+contrib+installed ?

Comment: please check this also https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/problem-compiling-nonfree-opencv-modules/31002/4 it might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I've spotted a repo which looks promising: https://github.com/ganwenyao/opencv_js
You can even try a few `aruco` demos here: https://ganwenyao.github.io/opencv_js/

It doesn't include `xfeature2d` already compiled but it's worth trying the same approach listed the repo's README.